# Pass data into a modal when clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, modal-dialog

New to angular. I am building an application where there is a meal card and you click on a button for a modal that has expanded information. I have a collapsible list of meals that each have a unique meal. When I click on the buttons only the first meal's data is displayed.

I am wondering how can I bind the data of whatever meal I click to the modal? I have separated my views into two html files. Below is some code.

Individual meals view:

```
<ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion" watch ng-controller= "mealView">
  <li>
    <!-- Meals -->
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion" ng-repeat = "meal in meals" >
      <li>
        <div class="collapsible-header">{{meal.name}}</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body">
          <div class= "row">
            <div class= "mealName col s4"> Name : {{meal.name}}</div>
            <div class= "mealRating col s4">Rating : {{meal.rating}}</div>
            <div class= "mealImg col s4">{{meal.image}}<br></div>
          </div>
          <div class= "row">
            <div class= "mealLocation col s5">Location : {{meal.location}}<br></div>
            <div class= "mealDate col s6">Date : {{meal.date}}<br></div>
          </div>
          <div class = "row">
            <div class= "mealNotes col s7">Notes : {{meal.notes}}</div>
            <!-- <a class="btn col s3 offset-s1 waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a> -->
            <a class='btn col s4' href='#mealModal' modal>Show Meal</a>
          </div>
          <div id="mealModal" class="modal">
             <mealinfo></mealinfo>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Modal view:

```
<div class="modal-content">
      <h4>{{meal.name}}</h4>
        <div class= "row">
           <div class= "mealName col s4"> Name : {{meal.name}}</div>
           <div class= "mealRating col s4">Rating : {{meal.rating}}</div>
           <div class= "mealImg col s4">{{meal.image}}<br></div>
        </div>
        <div class= "row">
           <div class= "mealLocation col s5">Location : {{meal.location}}<br></div>
           <div class= "mealDate col s6">Date : {{meal.date}}<br></div>
        </div>
        <div class = "row">
           <div class= "mealNotes col s7">Notes : {{meal.notes}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('mealinfo', function() {
  return  {
    restrict: 'AE',
    // use meal form template for directive
    templateUrl: '../views/mealInfo.html',
  };
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('mealView', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {

  $http.get("/meals")
   .then(function(data){
     console.log('Data: ', data.data)
     $scope.meals = data.data;
   })
}]);
```

Comment: suggestion: take the modal div out of the ng-repeat and set a scope variable (e.g. $scope.modalmeal) for the modal content when a meal is clicked.

Comment: so for example 
 ```<a class='btn col s4' href='#mealModal' modal ng-click="modalmeal">Show Meal</a>``` 

would I need to put the scope variable within the controller to define what modalmeal is? such as putting a ```$scope.modalmeal = data``` type thing?

Comment: you can probably have the `ng-click="showModal(meal)"` and use a showModal method that sets `$scope.meal = meal`.  then the modal code can stay unchanged. I added an answer below with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the `<div id="mealModal">` into the file `../views/mealInfo.html`
move the `<mealInfo>` tag outside of the ng-repeat

and replace it with

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" 
     data-target="#mealmodal" data-ng-click="showModal(meal)";>
        Launch demo modal
</button>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.showModal = function(m) {
    $scope.meal = m;
};
```

or replace it by

adding `ng-click="showModal(meal)"` to an existing `<div>, <li> or <a>` element

and in the controller:

```
$scope.showModal = function(m) {
    $scope.meal = m;
    $('#mealModal').modal('show');
};
```

Comment: I was able to get the info I wanted for each of the 'see meals' with the
``$scope.showModal = function(m) {
    $scope.meal = m;
};`` was able to see this by console logging. 

I am having difficulty actually getting the dialog box. I am adjusting the code you gave me to work with my materializecss that I am using. which requires <a></a> to work with the dialog box. 

currently have ```<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary col s4" data-toggle="modal" 
     data-target="mealmodal" data-ng-click="showModal(meal)" modal>Show Meal</a>``` I get a giant greyed out modal at the moment

Comment: Awesome, I saw your edits. Right now I am getting the info in all modals for just the last 'meal'. I am also getting a console log error of '.modal is not a function'. I looked it up and it is a jquery problem but i have jquery?

Comment: Hey I got it to work, thank you so much! I still have a lot to learn about scopes.